# Error in the tag ul

Tags: php, magento

Am trying to do a code as below

but there showing errors in the **ul**   as

**Syntax error:
expected: exit, if, identifier, variable, echo, do, while, for, foreach, endforeach, declare, switch, break, continue, function, return, try, throw, use, global, unset, isset, empty, class, interface, array, {, include, include_once, eval, require, require_once, print, ';', +, -, !, ~, ++, --, @, new, static, abstract, final, (, $**

My code is

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_top">
        <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
        <?php $counts=$helper->getStoreCategories()->count(); ?>
        <?php $cnt=0; $row=0; foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
             <?php if(($i==0)&&($cnt<$count)) ?>
                <?php $row++; ?>
                    <div class="footer_part">
                        <?php if($row==1):$no=4; ?>
                            <h2>Navigation</h2>
                        <?php else : $no=3; ?>
                            <h2></h2>
                        <?php endif ?>
                     <ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a></li>
                <?php  $i++; if($i==$no):?>
                    <?php $i=0;?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
               <?php endif; ?>
       <?php endforeach ?>

       </div>
</div>
```

Anybody please help me

Comment: why you are opening and closing php tag on every line?

Comment: <?php if(($i==0)&&($cnt<$count)):?> you forget :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do because $cnt will always equal 0 so you dont really need to check `$cnt<$count` because the foreach will only loop if the array/object count is greater than 0

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_top">
        <?php $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category'); ?>
        <?php //$counts = $helper->getStoreCategories()->count(); ?>

        <?php $cnt = 0;
        $row = 0;
        $i == 0;
        foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
             <?php if (($i == 0)):  $row++; ?>
                <div class="footer_part">
                    <?php if ($row == 1): $no = 4; ?>
                        <h2>Navigation</h2>
                    <?php else : $no = 3; ?>
                        <h2></h2>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul>
             <?php endif; ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a></li>
            <?php $i++; ?>  
            <?php if ($i == $no):  $i = 0; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
           <?php endif; ?>
       <?php endforeach ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be :

```
<?php endforeach ;?>
```

you missed `;` on third last line.

Answer (score 0):

i think u have an extra

```
<?php end if ?>
```

after `<ul>`.

please check... here is the code....

```
 <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $counts=$helper->getStoreCategories()->count(); ?>
    <?php $cnt=0; $row=0; foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
         <?php if(($i==0)&&($cnt<$count)) ?>
            <?php $row++; ?>
                <div class="footer_part">
                    <?php if($row==1):$no=4; ?>
                        <h2>Navigation</h2>
                    <?php else : $no=3; ?>
                        <h2></h2>
                    <?php endif ?>
                 <ul>
        //(deleted one endif here)
        <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a></li>
            <?php  $i++; if($i==$no):?>
                <?php $i=0;?>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <?php endif; ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: :I think there are 3 if statements and only 2 if closing.